# Does Sketchflow to Production now work in version 4?

Tags: silverlight, blend, sketchflow

Please ignore all the stuff about whether you should or not go from Sketch to Production...

Can it be done more easly now in version 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it has changed from V3 to V4. It should still be relatively simple to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for something more intuative than V3

Comment: It would be great to get your feedback on what you don't like about it, and how you want to use it. I can pass your feedback on to the product team for consideration in future versions.